# TRAC user permissions - do not allow to access page history

Tags: permissions, trac

In our group we had plain text passwords on our TRAC wiki pages. Now we are granting external users access to those wiki pages. Of course we removed the passwords from the page.

BUT: In the page history you can still see the passwords.

My question is: Is there a way to restrict the user rights to only see the current version of the page and not the page's history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with Trac core alone.

To be exact, likely you cannot see the passwords in the history (commented version lineup), but in the wiki page view of previous versions. This is where the issue starts to get complicated. Technically it is the same page view template, just with older content retrieved from the stack of wiki content by page name and version.

What you want is to just allow latest version views, but lock older ones. You write a mini-plugin to filter all version requests and redirect for user sessions without appropriate permission, say you define an extra permission WIKI_VIEW_REV and allow to inherit it by WIKI_ADMIN (and of course implicitly TRAC_ADMIN too).

Comment: Please respond, if you need more detailed hints, i. e. towards what extension points to use/hook in to get this done, if you're not so familiar with Trac by now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This sounds like what I need. Until now I have no experience with writing plugins for TRAC but will definitly try to get into this topic.

Comment: You can also restrict access to specific versions of a wiki page using [TracFineGrainedPermissions](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracFineGrainedPermissions). Due to a defect ([#8976](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/8976)) you will need Trac 1.0.2 or later, which is not yet release but should be released within a week or so. Ticket [#11263](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11263) may also be of interest to you - it suggests adding a syntax that would allow only the most recent version of a page to be viewed. Currently you can only grant or deny access on specific versions of a page.